# Cannot center the text inside circle

Tags: css, chakra-ui

using chakra-ui and css,
I want to center the text inside circle.

this is what I have:

```
<Td verticalAlign="middle">
 <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)">
  <GridItem colSpan={1} alignSelf="center">
   <Box className={testCss}>6</Box>
  </GridItem>
.
.
.
 </Grid>
</Td>

export const testCss = style({
    width: "15px",
    height: "15px",
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    color: "white",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
});
```

and this is how it looks like.
(number inside the circle is not vertically centered)

[image]

I've already tried
changing GridItem =>
display:flex and add set alignItems: "center" and justifyContent: "center" but it did not solve.

Does anyone know how to solve the issue?

Comment: you need to also adjust line-height on the font

Comment: Can you say exactly what is meant by 'centered'? For example instead of a number, a character with a descender like 'g' - where is that to be placed? Depending on the font and size will depend on where the baseline should be in relation to the circle.

Comment: ah...if I replace a number with character 'g' it's in center. I added `line-height="normal"` to "textCss" and it solved the issue :) thanks alot! @AHaworth